# Can Google crawl beyond Signin screen if username and password are not in the same screen

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, prelaunch

I am trying to make the `Pre-launch report` work well to cover more screens (beyond the signin screen) by providing `Sign-in credentials`, however after providing the testing account the crawl still cannot beyond the Sign-in screen. This is my configuration:

[image]

I can confirm the username/password resource name are correct, but in my app, they are in two separated screens.

I.e.: Input username (actually it requires a phone number) first then tap on `Next` button in this screen to see the screen for typing password (actually it is the `2fc` via SMS), 
and after typing in 2fc, the app logs the user in automatically, so there is no `Sign-in` button.

My question is does Google supports my use case stated as above? I.e.: if username and password are not in the same screen, is Google still able to crawl beyond the sign-in screen?

Answer (score 1):

The crawler will use the provided sign-in credentials when it matches the corresponding resource id on a given screen. So, having username and password on two different screens is not a problem. The tricky part is getting from one screen to another (in your case, it is clicking the Next button) such that the crawler has an opportunity to type in the password. If the crawler does not perform this step on its own, you can guide it with a [Roboscript](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842757?hl=en#zippy=%2Cprovide-a-robo-script-to-customize-the-test-path-of-a-java-app) - that is, instead of using sing-in credentials, record a Roboscript in which you type in the username, click Next, type in the password (basically, the steps you mentioned above), and then upload this Roboscript for your pre-launch report.